# Setting default locale

Tags: android, locale

We have an english as default, and translations for several other languages in our app. 
When user launches an app, we call `Locale.setDefault()` to set it to locale of our translations. For example, phone is running in spanish, but we have no spanish translations, we call `Locale.setDefault(Locale.US)`. We need this for time formatting, because libs use `Locale.getDefault()`.
It works perfectly until android 24. Android 24 "ignores" `Locale.setDefault()`. And all dates are formatted with device language but not app language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the solution was to change not only locale, but also locale inside configuration.

In application class

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    LocaleUtil.getInstance().invalidateCurrentLocale(base);
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    LocaleUtil.getInstance().invalidateCurrentLocale(this);
}
```

And this is LocaleUtil methods

```
public void invalidateCurrentLocale(Context context) {
    updateResources(context,
                    getLocaleOrDefault(getConfigLocale(context.getResources().getConfiguration())));
}

public Locale getConfigLocale(Configuration configuration) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24) {
        return configuration.locale;
    } else {
        return configuration.getLocales().get(0);
    }
}

private Locale getLocaleOrDefault(Locale locale) {
    if (AVAILABLE_LOCALES.contains(locale)) {
        return locale;
    }
    return DEFAULT_LOCALE;
}

private void updateResources(Context context, Locale locale) {
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
    config.setLocale(locale);
    res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In API 24 was added new method `setDefault (Locale.Category category,Locale newLocale)` Use [oficial docks](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault(java.util.Locale.Category,%20java.util.Locale))

Comment: But `setDefault (Locale newLocale)` was not deprecated and under the hood it uses `setDefault (Locale.Category category,Locale newLocale)` to set locale to both categories.